Rabbi Hirsch's original sefer
Can anyone direct me to or know where I can order or buy (in the US) the original German version of Rav Hirsch's commentary on the Torah?

Here's for free: https://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/freimann/content/titleinfo/1900331

@Kazibácsi I'm looking for a physical book. But thanks

One can order through the Amazon Site a reprint made by Forgotten books:
Vol. 1. Genesis or here
Vol. 2. Exodus or here
Vol. 3. Leviticus or here
Vol. 4. Numeri or here
Vol 5. Deuteronomium or here
Perhaps, it will be even cheaper to contact the Forgotten Books site directly. Forgotten books can also produce a premium hardcover for you and electronic version.
If you seek to buy original German editions, they also sometimes appear as separate volumes on Amazon. A good resource is the book search engine Bookfinder which has info from many antiquarian book stores in Europe and US.

Keep in mind that such reprints are almost definitely going to be printed in Fraktur, rather than Antqua, so unless you can read pre-Nazi German typography, you'll have a tough time with these

@NoachMiFrankfurt thank you for the tip. It is really helpful to read Wikipedia articles on Fraktur font https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur and on Antiqua font https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiqua_(typeface_class)

@NoachMiFrankfurt i noticed that. That's the only problem i have with this.

I'm also wondering if any other publisher had put it out?

@Shababnik i do not know. In some cases the reprints that i purchased were good quality. In some others, especially with pictures, the quality was not good. Sometimes to reduce the number of pages the images are skipped. While it may not be applicable to the R. Hirsch's commentary, the original printing is the best choice.

@YDJ who is the original publisher?

@Shababnik German publisher J. Kaufmann from Frankfurt am Main, 1898-1903. The electronic version should be available through Archive.org But it seems down. https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book//lookupid?key=olbp89922 also Sefaria has it https://www.sefaria.org/Rav_Hirsch_on_Torah%2C_Introduction.1?ven=Der_Pentateuch._%C3%9Cbersetzt_und_erl%C3%A4utert_von_Samson_Raphael_Hirsch,1903[de]&lang=bi

Is there no modern publisher for the german speakers that publishes the sefer?

@NoachMiFrankfurt Could you help with Shababnik's question if there is a modern German publisher of Der Pentateuch by R. Hirsch?

@Shababnik there seems to be Morascha publisher from Switzerland https://morascha.ch/produktkategorien/rabbiner_s-r-_hirsch/
